# How to avoid bypass of search bar rules?

Tags: wp-query, search

I’m building my site locally.

Since I want users to be able to write only specific terms in the search bar, I put a jQuery script in the wp-content\themes\sitename\js folder.
The script works fine, but I noticed that the script can be bypassed in a simple way.

For example, suppose that the search bar accepts only strings with 3 characters, so if I write `abcd` and press enter I get an error, but if I write `abc` and press enter then it works and the `Search Results` page will have the url

```
http://localhost/sitename/?s=abc
```

But it’s enough to modify the url to be

```
http://localhost/sitename/?s=abcd
```

and press enter, to bypass the search bar script.

How to avoid this?

I have 2 ideas, use the function `get_search_query`, or remove the keyword from the url so that independently from the keyword the url will be, for example

```
http://localhost/sitename/search
```

But I don't know how to use the function or how to remove the keyword from the url (if it is possibile).

Comment: This would need to be implemented in the server side PHP, a JS based solution might provide client-side validation, but you shouldn't rely on client-side restrictions to enforce things

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So isn't enough to show an error page when the search query does not respect the rules set in my .js file? Or, is there a way to know if the search query was inserted in the url rather than in the search bar, and then show an error page where it is written that searches through url editing is forbidden? Thanks

Comment: Look at it this way, if I turn off JS in my browser or your JS file fails to load, nothing would stop me breaking your validation rule, so it has to be server side

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `pre_get_posts` action to modify the search query on the server side. The [`pre_get_posts` Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Only_Display_Search_Results_After_Specific_Date) have some examples to get you started.

To target the main search query, try this:

```
function my_search_filter( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
            // Use $query->set(); to do stuff here.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't understand two things. (1) What does it mean server side for a localhost site? (2) Why do I need to modify the search query using `pre_get_posts`? Isn't enough to show an error page when the search query does not respect the rules set in my .js file?

Comment: 1. PHP files. 2. As Tom mentioned, you can circumvent javascript intentionally or unintentionally very easily. Anything on the client side (js,html,css) can be modified. PHP and data in Mysql cannot be modified by the end user. For these reasons, it's not enough to attempt to build this functionality in js. Using the method I've outlined, you can modify the search query using PHP before it gets to the database.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know about the difference, now it's more clear. So I'd like to ask you one more thing. A lot of files in the theme directory are .php, (for example search.php, index.php, functions.php, etc.), do you mean that all these files cannot be modified by the end user, while other files such as .js and .css can be modified (for example, by using the Inpect tool of the browser) and so are less secure?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.